# in tkinter how do I access text in a text box as a variable

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.10

What I am trying to achieve is being able to **click a button and get the text that the user has typed into a variable.**

I already have a button and the text box

```
from tkinter import *

def Enter_button():
    print()

ws = Tk()
ws.title('quick look up')
ws.geometry('300x300')
ws.config(bg='#ffffff')

message ='''Data here:'''


text_box = Text(
    ws,
    height=13,
    width=40
)
text_box.pack(expand=True)
text_box.insert('end', message)

Button(
    ws,
    text='Submit',
    width=15,
    height=2,
    command=Enter_button
).pack(expand=True)

ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is covered in the documentation, and there are countless examples on the internet. It's not clear why you need our help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in `Enter_button` you can add `text_box.get("1.0",END)`.

`get()` takes the start index and ending index of the text you want to get. So for all the text use: `.get("1.0",END)` as shown above and below.

So, for example:

```
from tkinter import *

def Enter_button():
    print(text_box.get("1.0",END))

ws = Tk()
ws.title('quick look up')
ws.geometry('300x300')
ws.config(bg='#ffffff')

message ='''Data here:'''

text_box = Text(
    ws,
    height=13,
    width=40
)
text_box.pack(expand=True)
text_box.insert('end', message)

Button(
    ws,
    text='Submit',
    width=15,
    height=2,
    command=Enter_button
).pack(expand=True)

ws.mainloop()
```